# Why is Diana a Huntress?

Tags: greek, comparative, roman

Everyone knows that [Diana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diana_(mythology)), as well as her Greek parallel [Artemis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis), are hunter goddesses, but few seem to know why.  From where does this association originate?

Answer (score 1):

The answer, my dear Watson, is threefold.

*[*

**Fold: 1**

{Artemis and Apollo were in the womb for seven months. Legends tell us that Apollo, after emerging from the womb when Leto was attended to by all Goddesses except Hera, immediately asked for some things like weapons and musical instruments, and was generally annoying. Artemis stayed with this guy for *seven months*. So, she got a very bad opinion of males.}

**OR**

**Fold: 2**

{As legends say, Artemis, after coming out of the womb, helped to deliver Apollo. During this, she saw how much pain Leto was going through during childbirth. She became the Goddess of childbirth. This made her afraid of the pain which she would experience in having children.}

**OR**

**Fold: 3**

{While going to Olympus from Delos, she heard stories of how badly the male Gods treated her wives, cheating on them every other week and so. Not to say how the young girls were married to those who offered the highest price, even if the groom was old, fat, or stinky.}

*]*

So, she made Zeus swear to let her stay a virgin.

And so that she did not feel alone, ahe took about 80 maidens, Pan's best dogs, and a few other things, and went hunting. So she became the Goddess of it.

And since Roman myths are basically Greek ones with names changed, Diana became that too.

> Almost all my information was taken from *Percy Jackson and the Greek Gods (Rick Riordan)* and Wikipedia.

Comment: I gave an up-vote for enthusiasm, although I hope you will clarify your answer.  For instance, in Fold: 1, did Artemis ask for or get presents too?  Did she also get a bow when her brother did?  Does Riordan mention anything about Orion and Artemis?  (I'd also strongly recommend a budding scholar like yourself check out Riordan's reprint of Robert Graves' [The Greek Myths](https://www.amazon.com/Greek-Myths-Penguin-Classics-Deluxe/dp/0143106716). It has an excellent index for convenient search on a stunning array of characters from the Myths:)

Comment: @DukeZhou Thanks for the upvote.In fold 1, Artemis asked for everything.""

Comment: Not again! Sorry, sorry.   She had Hephaestus make a bow for her. I don't remember Riordan telling anything about when Apollo got his bow. About Orion, there are several different versions. He was an excellent hunter, that is agreed upon. He joined the hunt, that too is. What follows is unclear. Some legends say he had lustful thoughts, or maybe did lustful actions, with one of the hunters. A few say this happened to Artemis herself. Riordan himself goes with the version that he went mad somehow on a hunting trip. Whatever the reason,he got killed by a specially conjured scorpion,made by Gaia.

Comment: Later, he was also made a constellation, alongwith the scorpion. An addition to my previous comment: Since he webt mad in Riordan's version, he started Killin every animal he saw. This angered Artemis and Gaia, so one of them sent the scorpion, which killed him

Comment: Hey Malay!  Haven't seen your mytho-mind on SE:Mythology lately...

Comment: @DukeZhou Yeah. Sorry about that, but as you might see from my intense activity on Math.SE, I've been preparing for Math Olympiads.

Comment: I will definitely check out your math posts!  *(I'm currently banned from regular math for asking too many naive question about set theory and sudoku, and general intransigence--but still quite interested in the field in general, having have very poor mathematical training as a child, but I can still vote! ;)*  PS: Good luck at the Math Olympiads!

Answer (score -1):

In a nutshell Hera is the Queen now.  Artemis is the Queen of the Jungle.
After how harshly hera treated her, she's a shoe-in for the *prophesized* one....

That's why she's the Queen of the hunt.  She just needs a counterpart to Hera's Zeus to crown her queen.

And this is also why Apollo decided to go Bisexual one time with Hyacinthus.  Hyacinthus was not for him, but for Artemis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is unclear what is the relation here between Hera and Artemis.